# Fourier transform of cos(1/x) (as tempered distribution)

Tags: improper-integrals, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

I'm trying to find the (rigorous) Fourier transform of $f(x)=\cos(1/x).$ Since $f$ is not in $L^1$ nor $L^2$, some singularity should appear, and I need to use the Fourier transform in $S'(\mathbb R)$. Thus, I'm looking for the computation of
$$T_f(\hat \phi)=\int_{\mathbb R}\cos(1/x)\hat \phi(x)dx,$$
for $\phi \in S(\mathbb R)$, where $\hat \phi$ is the Fourier transform of $\phi$. Can someone help in the computation or give a reference in the literature?

Comment: Connected: the concept of "chirp" in signal processing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp).

Comment: $\cos(1/x) - 1$ is in $L^1$, so $\mathcal F[x \mapsto \cos(1/x) - 1]$ is the regular distribution corresponding to the ordinary function
$$\int_{\mathbb R} (\cos(1/x) - 1) e^{i \xi x} dx,$$
which has a closed form in terms of the Bessel function $J_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your replay @Maxim, that is exactly what I'm looking for. Do you have a reference for the computation of the Fourier transform of $\cos(1/x)−1$ in terms of $J_1$?

Comment: I don't have a reference for that particular formula. It can be derived by the Mellin convolution method. $\cos(\xi \sqrt u)$ and $\cos(1/\sqrt u) - 1$ are Meijer G-functions with arguments of the form $k u$, so the integral is again a G-function, which simplifies to a Bessel function. The end result is
$$\int_{\mathbb R} (\cos(1/x) - 1) e^{i \xi x} dx =
-\frac {\pi J_1(2 \sqrt \xi)} {\sqrt \xi},
\quad \xi > 0.$$
Reducing the integral of $\sin^2(u/2) \cos(\xi/u)/u^2$ to [Schlafli's integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9.E19) might be a more direct way.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is perfect!!